# Form submit name get value

Tags: forms, submit

I have a form and using a normal submit button with no name like this below.

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Everything works fine like it is. My question is there a way I can give it a name say random numbers like this below.

```
 <input type="submit" name="R312321321" value="Submit" />
```

Then when I submit can I get the value of the name of the submit button like if it was a hidden input. I can't use a hidden input for what I'm doing. The reason I want to do the submit button this way is browser macros look for the name. If the name is always changing its harder for their macro to work. Once I get the value of the submit button I can authenticate it which I have something already created just need to get the value of the submit in php.

Thank you

Comment: This can be done, but I'm curious -- is there any particular reason why you can't have a hidden field to check the name of?

Comment: The browser imacros people use is like some one really entering in data. I have a captcha but once after that their free to do what ever. The problem is they user their imacro and if it's hidden the macro don't care. If a name changes on something they use it will timeout. So the submit button changes it's name I want to give it some info so if they alter their macro to ignore the name it won't work still I just need to pass some data through the submit button.

Comment: What I mean is, you could generate a random number and make that the name of the submit button, but then you could also have a hidden element and give that the same value as the name of the submit button. ie <button name="123456"> <hidden val="123456" name="trustyHidden"> <-- now you can just grab the value of trustyHidden and use that as the name of button

Comment: I see but with the macro it will pass the hidden field correctly just like a normal user would. All the macros I tested have a problem when the submit button name is changed. To stop them from removing the name and it will allow them still to use it. I want to add some Vars in there so if it's removed it will not allow them to use it.

Comment: The hidden value will ALWAYS be passed.  It's simply a way for you, on the back-end, to check to see if the submit button was clicked.  You're looking for the name of a submit button, and hte hidden value can always store that.

Comment: My question is how do I get the name of the submit button on the back end once the user clicks on it in PhP. Thanks

Comment: That's precisely what I'm saying.  Pass a hidden element which will always have the VALUE = NAME_OF_SUBMIT_BUTTON and will always have a static NAME.  So, you'll always have that hidden element passed, so then you will have the name of the submit button

Comment: <input type="submit" name="R312321321" value="Submit" /> <input type="hidden" name="staticName" value="R312321321" /> then on the backend isset($_POST['$_POST['staticName']'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this would work. However, the spec says otherwise about input names beginning with numbers.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

After you submit the form you will have a key value pair

```
[312321321] => Submit
```

Comment: I can change it to letters then just need to figure out how to pass it through when it's submitted in PhP.

Comment: You would just check if the key exists, what serverside scripting language are you using ?